# Magento 2 Attribute Not Show In Navigation

Tags: php, magento, magento2, magento2.1

I have a problem when applying magento 2.1.9 to my project.

My attribute is **ab_size**

I have created that attribute with code blow.

```
$categorySetup = $this->categorySetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $entityTypeId = $categorySetup->getEntityTypeId(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY);

        foreach ($singleAttributeCodes as $key => $label) {
            $categorySetup->removeAttribute($entityTypeId, $key);
            $categorySetup->addAttribute(
                $entityTypeId,
                $key,
                [
                    'type' => 'varchar',
                    'label' => $label,
                    'input' => 'select',
                    'required' => false,
                    'sort_order' => $sortOrder,
                    'visible' => true,
                    'user_defined' => true,
                    'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                    'filterable' => 0,
                    'visible_on_front' => true,
                    'used_in_product_listing' => true,
                    'group' => $group,
                    'apply_to' => 'simple,configurable,bundle,downloadable,grouped',
                ]
            );
        }
```

With config in the backend.

1. Enable filter (with result) **done**
2. Category Is Anchor **done**
3. Reindex **done**
4. Enable Category flat **done**
5. Enable Product flat **done**
6. Reindex all data **done**
7. Clear cache **done**
8. Use magento clean doesn't have any extension **done**
9. Check with attribute **color** (done it show in navigation)
10. Product Price **Show**
11. Category **Show**

    **about my system information**
12. CentOS 7.0
13. Litespeed
14. Php7.0
15. Magento CE 2.1.9

*I have debugged that the product collection buckets return empty*

I think that problem with creating attribute code, has anyone got the same problem.

Thank anyone have tips.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With **select** attribute we must use type of **int**..

Answer (score -1):

I think you have messed your attributes with this code.
Looking at it, it removes all the attributes and adds them but as type varchar, which may not be applicable to all attributes.
I would suggest resetting your Magento database, and then add the attribute using code like the following.

As I do not know what you are planning to use this attribute, some of the settings bellow may not apply to your use case.

```
 $categorySetup->addAttribute(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
        'ab_size',
        [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'backend' => '',
            'frontend' => '',
            'label' => 'AB Size',
            'input' => 'select',
            'class' => '',
            'source' => '',
            'backend' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\ArrayBackend',
            'global' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
            'visible' => true,
            'required' => false,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'default' => 0,
            'searchable' => false,
            'filterable' => true,
            'comparable' => false,
            'visible_on_front' => true,
            'used_in_product_listing' => true,
            'unique' => false,
            'apply_to' => ''
        ]
    );
```

Comment: Reset database is an important thing on LIVE database.

Comment: @HoangHieu I do not see why you down-voted my answer. Clearly setting all attributes to varchar, which your original code did, was a wrong approach.

Comment: *I would suggest resetting your Magento database*, this suggestion is not recommended.

Comment: Your original attempt has changed data types of the columns in the Magento database. You are free to do whatever you want to rectify the changed data types.